# Select Distinct em Doctrine e Symfony

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

Oi, tenho uma tabela de criação de album de fotos. O meu código faz 1 insert para cada imagem adicionada no album de fotos. Eu tenho um grid para a exibição dos albums para o usuário visualizar. Eu quero fazer um distinct dos albuns duplicados.

Eu tenho este tipo de código:

```
      $select = Doctrine_Query::create()
                                ->select('DISTINCT s.idAlbum')
                                ->addSelect('s.imagens_data, s.publicar')
                                ->from('tbimagens s')->getSqlQuery();
      print_r($select);
      die;
```

Este é o meu resultado em Sql:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
   t.id AS t__id, 
   t.idalbum AS t__idalbum, 
   t.imagens_data AS t__imagens_data, 
   t.publicar AS t__publicar 
 FROM tbimagens t
```

Viram que o select traz o Id da tabela ? Este Id está me impossibilitando de fazer o select correto pois todos os Ids já são naturalmente distintos.

Alguém pode me ajudar nesta query? 
Estou utilizando o symfony 1.4 e doctrine 1.2

Comment: Qual seu critério pra decidir se um álbum está duplicado ou não?

Comment: se a quantidade de vezes que ele aparecer no grid for maior que a quantidade de imagens upadas para ele.

Answer (score 1):

```
$select = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->from('tbimagens s')
  ->select('DISTINCT s.id_album')
  ->addSelect('s.imagens_data, s.publicar')
  ->getSqlQuery();
```

cara tenta ver se você não esta passadno um parametro errado, no caso a chave estrangeira para o album. E também a ordem como você cria o select, mas realmente ele não pode colocar no seu select o id da tabela.

Uma outra solução seria voce colocar um unique na chave estrangeira.